# Emacs control and super key modifiers used together

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am using Emacs 25.2 on Mac OS X 10.12.4. I am trying to set the following command for the previous buffer command.

```
(global-set-key [(C s j)] 'previous-buffer)
```

My super key is the CMD key. This key binding works for the right CMD key but when I try with the left CMD key, I get the following message.

```
<C-s-268632074> is undefined
```

Why is my left CMD key treated differently?

Answer (score 0):

This works at Debian for example:

`(global-set-key [(control c)(super \))] 'MyCommand)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work in Mac OS X.